# Ruby On Rails : has_many collection not updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, has-many

I have a problem when i update an object in a has_many association :

```
l = self.posts.where(...)
l.each do |item|
  item.increment!(:nb, 2)         
  item.update
  item.save
end
```

When I do :

```
logger.info Post.all.inspect
logger.info self.posts.inspect
```

The posts are updated with the first line but not with the second

Is there a way to force the update or am i doing something wrong? I also tried to disable the cache but it still the same problem.

Comment: actually you don't need to call `update` and `save` after the `increment!` command, `increment!` already writes the data to the db

Comment: also you can call `.reload` on the item later, to reload it. Looks like the increment command does not updates the instance in your case.

Comment: I think you have to `reload` to see the changes at the database level e.g. `self.posts.reload.inspect`

Comment: Yury Lebedev : I tried also with update_attributes and +=

Comment: Thank you very much @engineersmnky and @ Yury Lebedev! Reload works fine. So I need to reload a collection after each update?

Comment: only sometimes. If the method updates the database directly but does not reflect on the instance itself like `increment!` does.

Comment: I'll stay with reload solution. I tried also with nb+=2 and item.save(item.attributes) and same issue. Anyway, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
logger.info self.posts(true).inspect
```

By default, [`force_reload`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many) is `false`.

Comment: Thank you it's works also, but i'll stay with reload.